# Next/previous posts link not showing at all

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

i'm creating a new blog in wordpress

and i got a problem with index.php file

the button is not showing and i tried a lot and nothing change

this is the code in index.php

```
    <div class="block n-p">

<?php previous_posts_link(); ?>
||
<?php next_posts_link(); ?>
</div>
    <!--End block-->
```

any Advice please?

and thank you for the Support.

Comment: Maybe stupid question, but do you have any other posts? Because, if you dont have, this will not work.

Comment: yes of course i have !!!

Comment: Ok,can you give us some relevant code to look at? Maybe you have some loop, and next/previous links wont show up

Comment: i fixed, but thank you very much for lookink..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it should be

```
<?php previous_post(); ?>    <?php next_post(); ?>
```

without the "_link"